# Exclude specific kafka partition while fetching the messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are reading Kafka messages from few topics. Each topics have two partitions where one partition in not getting use to populate the message.(partition 0 is used where 1 is not getting used. It was created for future purpose) We are using Spring Kafka consumer where we are creating the consumers programmatically configurating ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and register with org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.We do not want to subscribe our consumers to partition number 1 of any topics. Is there any way to exclude it?

We have tried to implement a ConsumerRebalanceListener but I believe on onPartitionsAssigned(Collection var1), we can not remove those partitions.

Comment: Have you tried providing partition=0 to the KafkaListener annotation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use manual assignment instead of group management.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Spring for Apache Kafka.

See Kafka Clients API like `ConsumerPartitionAssignor`. You may use a `RoundRobinAssignor` for inspiration how to skip undesired partitions and assign them to your subscriptions.

Then you use your custom class for `partition.assignment.strategy` property of your consumer.

This article give more information about assignments in consumer group: https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3

Comment: You can also manually assign partitions - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-container and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#manual-assignment